# I want mount Resque on a subpath in your existing Rails 4

Tags: resque

rails3  resque(1-x-stable) I do like this at my routes.rb :

require 'resque/server'
mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"

but now I use rails 4 resque(2.0.0.pre.1),  it has same problems like this:

uninitialized constant Resque::Server (NameError)

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the version 1.25.2 of the gem works well in rails 4.

You need to change this line

```
gem "resque", "~> 2.0.0.pre.1", github: "resque/resque"
```

by this in your **gemfile**

```
gem "resque"
```

and remove require 'resque/server' from your **routes.rb**